# Why are some Composite C1 'Page Template Features' 'html' and some 'xml'?

Tags: c1-cms

I am new to Composite C1 - and am using Page Template Features.

I have noticed in the sample file that some are market .html - and some marked .xml (even though the latter appear to just be html pages).

is there a reason for this? Do I need to be aware of it?

Answer (score 2):

In the C1 Console, .html-based features will open in Visual Editor, .xml-based - in Code Editor.

For more information, please see http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Page-Template-Features/Creating#Visual-vs-Markup

For a lengthy technical discussion on this feature, please see http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/404072

Comment: The strange thing is - the .xml 'page template feature' just appears to be straight HTML. Why does it have an xml extension?

Comment: The 'page template feature' rely on file extension when the default editor is chosen. .xml files give you a code editor, .html files give you a visual editor. Using the extension of a file is a simple way to select a default editor type. 
The reasoning behind having two editor types are that some files may be mostly <head /> tags or otherwise unsuited for visual editing, while the visual editor is convenient for less technical users and allow them to change things like the phone number in a page footer.

Comment: so '.xml' files are still html files - they just open in source view? Seems like a strange decision, as the file is still an html file no?!

Comment: Composite C1 doesn't work with pure HTML. It works with XHTML which is essentially XML that mimicks HTML4. So basically you work with XML in both cases whether it is .xml or .html-based files that stand for page template features.